# Swapping two strings inside an excel cell with each other based on orientation within the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out how to swap certain characters with each other within a cell based on their orientation within the cell and not the actual characters themselves. This is because the strings are random. So for example, I would like to switch the 7th,8th, and 9th character with the 11th,12th, and 13th character.

How can I replicate this in a formula?
[image: Picture Example]

```
50000-ABC-123
50000-DEF-546
50000-GFD-456
50000-EDG-875
50000-SDF-304

50000-123-ABC
50000-546-DEF
50000-456-GFD
50000-875-EDG
50000-304-SDF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is to use `FILTERXML` if you have the newest version of Excel, which will work even if the strings come in different lengths, but follow the same format (i.e. numbers-letters-numbers).

For example:

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",1,
INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(I2,"-","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),{1,3,2}))
```

[image]

Thanks to @JvdV for both the edit recomendation and the very encompassing explanation on `FILTERXML` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml)

Comment: Nice, did not think to use ```INDEX```. Have edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Just use this formula in B1 and pull it down

```
=LEFT(A1,5) & RIGHT(A1,4) & MID(A1,6,4)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!